# ng serve doesn't start Anguiar on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I am using Linux Ubuntu and when typing `ng serve` this opens:[image]

I am able to start the app by running `npm start`, because the script runs `ng serve`. However I need to run `ng serve` with `sudo`, so that it recognizes files changes.

Putting `sudo ng serve` into the start script also doesn't work.

Comment: @FloarianLudewig have you check your `package.json` this is present `"start": "ng serve"` or not?

Comment: yeah it is there :D

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install ng globally

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Comment: That's strange, I thought I did this already. But it worked, thanks!